# C++ what is the idiomatic way to avoid pointers?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have a method which takes const ref to a set.  I want to call it and m.b. pass a set to it.  If I have it.  So first I see if I have a set:

```
const auto& it = mapOfSets.find("token");
if (it != std::end(mapOfSets)) {
  myFunction(it.second);
} else {
  MySetType emptySet;
  myFunction(emptySet);
}
```

What is an idiomatic way of doing this?  I don't like the above because call to myFunction is repeated twice and there is a few other arguments, so there is some unnecessary code duplication.

The C programmer in me just wants to change the function to accept a pointer and pass nullptr if set is not found, but i feel that C++ is all about avoiding pointers now?..

Comment: The type of `it.second` is `MySetType`, right?

Comment: yes hopefully it is

Comment: C++ is about avoiding raw **owning** pointers.  Using the pointer like you would a reference is still okay.

Comment: You could make a helper that returns `optional<reference_wrapper<const T>>` for a lookup and use its `value_or` function. Rather awkward without the native support for references, though.

Comment: @NathanOliver some also recommend to avoid raw non-owning pointers, because it's often not a safe assumption when reading code that the author knows about and follows the recommendation to avoid raw owning pointers

Comment: `const auto& it =` is a pessimisation;  `auto it = ` would be better in every way

Comment: Another option would be for your function to have two overloads; one taking an iterator and one taking no argument.

Comment: @M.M I can see that.  I wished we had something like `std::non_owning` to allow some documentation in the code itself.

Comment: @NathanOliver: [std::experimental::observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a helper function to find a set in the map then you can return a reference to a special empty set in the case that you did not find anything:

```
const MySetType& find(const MyMapType& mapOfSets, const std::string& key) {
    auto it = mapOfSets.find(key);
    if (it != std::end(mapOfSets)) {
        return it->second;
    }
    static const MySetType emptySet;
    return emptySet;
}
```

Then your calling code is simply:

```
myFunction(find(mapOfSets, "token"));
```

Comment: This is ugly but I like it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the conditional operator:

```
myFunction(it != mapOfSets.end() ? it->second : MySetType{});
```

I don't think there is an idiomatic way though.

Comment: At least this is DRY

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a handwritten `optional_reference` that can reference `nullptr` but will `throw` when dereferencing it and has no additional `bool`

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>

class null_access_exception: public std::logic_error
{
    using base = std::logic_error;
public:
    null_access_exception():
        base("Try to dereference null optional_reference!")
    {}
};

template <class Ptr_t>
class optional_reference
{
    using self = optional_reference;
    using reference = decltype(*std::declval<Ptr_t>());
    Ptr_t ptr = nullptr;

public:
    optional_reference() = default;
    optional_reference(const self&) = default;

    self& operator = (const self&) = delete;

    template <class U>
    constexpr optional_reference(U &&obj) noexcept: 
        ptr(std::addressof(obj))
    {}

    constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept
    { return has_value(); }

    constexpr bool has_value() const noexcept
    { return ptr != nullptr; }

    constexpr auto& value() const
    {
        if (!has_value())
            throw null_access_exception();

        return *ptr;
    }

    template <class U>
    constexpr auto& value_or(U &&obj) const noexcept
    {
        if (has_value())
            return *ptr;
        else
            return reference(std::forward<U>(obj));
    }
};
```

and then

1. Change `myfunction` so that it accept `optional_reference` and then check it.
2. Wrap it like below.

   constexpr const static auto null_set();
   void Myfunction(optional_wrapper ref)
   {
       myfunction(ref.value_or(null_set));
   }